# Unix script / replace string in file from variable and move into another directory

Tags: linux, unix, scripting

I'm trying to do a script which find specific string in .txt files and replace by variable. I don't want to change original files but do the copies and then move into another (specific) directory.  Let's assume 3 .txt files:

files.txt,
file2.txt
file3.txt

First step is to find string "string1" and "string2" in all .txt files and do the copies (eg. tmp files).
Second is to replace a string by variable $1 and $2 (working on tmp files).
Then move all of them to 'directoryname' directory.

That's what I'v got:

```
#!/bin/bash 


echo "$1 - first parameter"
echo "$2 - second"



configurer() { 


for file in *.txt 

do 

    echo "Processing file .... $file" 

    orig_file=$file 

    tmp_file=$orig_file.tmp 

    cp $orig_file $tmp_file 


sed "s/string1/$1/g;s/string2/$2/g" $tmp_file 

   mv $tmp_file directorname/$orig_file 



done 

} 


configurer 



echo "Done ..."
```

It's almost correct, (correct move into another directory, do the tmp files), but sed function doesn't work as it should and I have no idea why. Could anyone take a look ? 
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below sed, its always problem with sed with variable

```
sed -i -e 's/string1/'"$1"'/g'  -e 's/string2/'"$2"'/g' $tmp_file
```

let me know if it works
for your piece of code

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "$1 - first parameter" 
echo "$2 - second"    
configurer() { 
for file in *.txt 
do     
echo "Processing file .... $file"     
orig_file=$file     
tmp_file=$orig_file.tmp     
cp $orig_file $tmp_file 
sed -i -e 's/string1/'"$1"'/g'  -e 's/string2/'"$2"'/g' $tmp_file 
mv $tmp_file directorname/$orig_file 
done } 
configurer  $1 $2
echo "Done ..."
```

Comment: Now I notice that "move operation" is working OK, but it moves original file... Even if I use sed "s/string1/'Mytext'/g;s/string2/Mytext2/g" $tmp_file  , Sed function is not done on temp files...

Comment: sorry added the -i switch in answer. pls check

Comment: Unfortanely it replace "string1" by NULL value. Instead of value from variable in output file is null : (

Comment: Ok, it seems to work correctly. I delete configurer() {}. have no idea why but it works now : ) thanks

Comment: I have edited the answer as per your script. Removing configure() works because configure is not recognizing the $1 and $2 within it. the function configure creates a child shell for its execution so unable to inherit $1 and $2 from parent shell.